Exporting environments similar to 'tikzexport'
Is there any environment that besides displaying the code on the pdf file also exports the code inside as a standalone pdf on a specified directory? something similar to how the export library from tikz exports figures to a directory.
I want to use it so i can access the math solutions and export them to excel easily.
I could simply just use a standalone and copy paste the code but i wanted something that would be more easy and fast.
Desired result
The desired result would be to process my document into a pdf as normal but everything that i wrapped inside a specific environment to be saved in a specific directory in different pdf files.

maybe https://ctan.org/pkg/robust-externalize is worth a look (I don't know if it can do equations)

Do you want to export the code or the resulting pdf? For a pdf with one page per, e.g., displayedmath or other elements, you could use package preview. Some elements can be activated by option, others can be defined using the preview environment.

I want to export the resulting pdf, not all of it as latex already compiles the pdf, but the section that i highlight (between an environment maybe) to be unaffected in the final pdf but also saved into a directory as if it was being processed standalone.

So you can use package preview and switch between a PDF with only the highlights and a PDF with everything using option active or not. See the manual for more information.

I tried but keep crashing as im also using the tikz export library, i decided to try creating my own little environment with the scontents package

memoize could do this, but you'd have to tell it what to externalise. E.g. you could tell it to externalise all environment xxxs or whatever. You could then switch off use of the externalised images when you wanted the document to compile normally i.e. without including the externalised images as graphics. But the externs won't be as if compiled standalone. They'll compile as they would in your document i.e. same format etc. I don't know what tikzexport is, though.

tikzexport or the export library is probably a typo for the tikzlibrary external and the corresponding \tikzexternalize command.
